# Reuse of libcurl handles

Tags: c++, c, tcp, libcurl

I'm using libcurl for an application in a thread that needs to send the same URL request every configuarble amount of minutes, so I have a loop in my thread that looks pretty much like this:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();    
while(!mStopRun)
    {   
        try
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(....);
            curl_easy_setopt(....);
            curl_easy_perform(....);
            sleep(configurable_period)
        }
    }
curl_easy_cleanup(mEasyHandle);
curl_global_cleanup();
```

For some unknown reason I see some TCP problems on wireshark hapenning consistantly. Apparently the TCP connection is not being closed properly:
[image: wireshark screenshot]

Using a fresh handle at each iteration solved the problem, but is this truly the best practice ? Isn't there a way I can reuse the same connection and keep sending in the same frequency ? (maybe configure something on client side or server side).

Comment: According to the [documentation for libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html), it always tries to make a persistent connection to the server.

Comment: It is perfectly normal to not close a connection to an HTTP server when you plan to send another request to it. See also `Connection:` header, and note that persistent connections are the default in HTTP/1.1 unless `Connection: close` is specified.

Comment: I've forgot to note, but I'm using libcurl version 7.17.1.
Is this behavior relevant for this version ? If so, why do I get these connection closures ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I do see Connection: close on server's http response, but not on client's request. Does this mean that I should resolve it on server's side ?

Comment: If the server chooses to send `Connection: close`, it should go ahead and actually close the connection after completing the request (RFC2616 8.1.2.1). It's not clear why it wants to do either, but in any case, it should do neither or both (that is, either not send `Connection: close` and keep the connection open; or send `Connection: close` and actually close the connection after sending the response).

Comment: libcurl version 7.17.1 is *ridiculously* old. More than 7.5 years to be specific. Upgrading to a modern version would be sensible for numerous reasons. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/releases.html